# Ruby error with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

how to make route from appointment/new51 action to create51 action ? because it automatically redirect me to create and I don't want this. I am new in Ruby and I have lots of problems with my school project but it is almost finished:)
Routes.rb:

```
ZOZ::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :refferals do
  collection do
        get 'new51' 
    end
     member do
        get 'show'
  end
  end

  #17 potwierdzanie rejestracji
  resources :appointments do 
    collection do
        get 'search' 
        get 'search_result'
        get 'to_confirm'
        get 'new51' 
    end
    member do
        put :confirm
        put :create51
    end
  end

  resources :clinics do
  collection do 
        get 'index51'
    end
  member do
        get 'show51s'
  end
  end

  resources :doctors do
    collection do 
        get 'index51a'
        get 'index51'
    end
    member do
        get 'show51s'
        get 'show51ss'
    end
  end

  resources :patients do
    collection do 
        get 'select51'
        get 'index51'
    end
    member do
        get 'show51s'
        get 'show51ss'
    end
  end

  get "welcome/index2"
  get "welcome/index"

  get 'appointments/create'
  get 'appointments/move' => 'appointments#move'
  post 'appointments/move' => 'appointments#doctors_list'
  get 'appointments/move/:id' => 'appointments#doctor_appointments', as: :doctor_appointments
  get 'appointments/change_appointment/:id' => 'appointments#change_appointment', as: :change_appointment
  get 'appointments/change_doctor_and_appointment/:id' => 'appointments#change_doctor_and_appointment', as: :change_doctor_and_appointment
  get 'appointments/success' => 'appointments#success'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):


  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Appointments_controller:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_appointment, only: [:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]
  before_filter :load_wizard, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]

  def search
  end

  def new51
    @doctors_workplace = DoctorsWorkplace.scoped
    @doctors_workplace = @doctors_workplace.where(doctor_id: Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id2]).id) 
    @appointment = Appointment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @appointment }
    end
  end

  def create51
  @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @appointment, status: :created, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html do 
          @schedules = Schedule.scoped
          @schedules = @schedules.where(doctor_id: Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id2]).id) 
          render action: "new51"
        end
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def search_result
    d = params[:date]
    data = Date.new(d["(1i)"].to_i, d["(2i)"].to_i, d["(3i)"].to_i)
  #szukanie pacjenta
    @patients = Patient.scoped
    @patients = @patients.where(pesel: params[:pesel])

  if params[:imie] != ""
      @patients = @patients.where(imie: params[:imie])
   end

   if params[:nazwisko] != ""
      @patients = @patients.where(nazwisko: params[:nazwisko])
   end
   #szukanie doctora
   opcja = 0
   @doctors = Doctor.scoped
  if params[:imie_lekarza] != ""
      @doctors = @doctors.where(imie_lekarza: params[:imie_lekarza])
      opcja = 1
   end

   if params[:nazwisko_lekarza] != ""
      @doctors = @doctors.where(nazwisko_lekarza: params[:nazwisko_lekarza])
      opcja = 1
   end
   #zlaczenie
    @patient_appo = @patients.first.appointments.where(:data_godzina_wizyty => data.beginning_of_day..data.end_of_day, potwierdzona: false)
   if opcja == 1
        @doctors_appo = @doctors.first.appointments.where(:data_godzina_wizyty => data.beginning_of_day..data.end_of_day, potwierdzona: false)
        @appointments = @patient_appo & @doctors_appo
    else
        @appointments = @patient_appo
   end
  end

  def to_confirm
    session['last_search'] = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    @patient = Patient.find(@appointment.patient_id)
    if @appointment.doctor_id != nil
        @doctor = Doctor.find(@appointment.doctor_id)
    end
    if @appointment.refferal_id != nil
        @refferal = Refferal.find(@appointment.refferal_id)
    end
  end

  def confirm
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    @appointment.potwierdzona = true
    if @appointment.save
      #redirect_to :back, notice: 'Rejestracja zostala pomyslnie potwierdzona.'
      redirect_to session[:last_search], notice: 'Rejestracja zostala pomyslnie potwierdzona.'
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Niestety wystapil blad. Prosze sprubowac pozniej'
    end
  end

  def index
    @appointments = Appointment.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @appointment = @wizard.object
    @clinics = Clinic.all
    @doctors = Doctor.all
  end

  public
  def findDoctorViaClinic( clinic )
    return( (Clinic.find(  clinic   )).doctors.uniq )
  end
  helper_method :findDoctorViaClinic

  def findScheduleViaDoctor(d)
    s = Schedule.includes(:doctors_workplace).where(doctors_workplace_id: (DoctorsWorkplace.includes(:doctor).where(doctor_id: d)) ).where(taken: 0) 
    return s
  end
    helper_method :findScheduleViaDoctor


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @appointment = @wizard.object
    if @wizard.save 
     s = ( Schedule.find( @appointment.schedule.id ) )
     s.taken = true
     s.save
      redirect_to @appointment, notice: "Appointment saved!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @wizard.save
      redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @appointment.destroy
    redirect_to appointments_url
  end

private

  def load_appointment
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def load_wizard
    @wizard = ModelWizard.new(@appointment || Appointment, session, params)
    if self.action_name.in? %w[new edit]
      @wizard.start
    elsif self.action_name.in? %w[create update]
      @wizard.process
    end
  end
end
```

_form51:

```
<%= form_for(@appointment) do |f| %>
  <% if @appointment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@appointment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this appointment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @appointment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :data_godzina_wizyty %><br />
  <%=
    options = { start_year: 2.year.from_now.year,
                end_year: 2013,
                include_blank: true,
                default: nil }
    f.datetime_select :data_godzina_wizyty, options
  %>
  <!--<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' :data_wizyty > -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :doctor_id, :value => Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id2]).id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, :value => Patient.find(session[:current_patient_id]).id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Utworz wizyte" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What about `services/model_wizard.rb`? the error in that class.

Comment: Look at my edited question, I have another error and I think this may be easier to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wymaga_Potwierdzenia != wymaga_potwierdzenia
```

Correct to the right method/column name.

Comment: @smiaro Stop changing the question. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Otherwise the comments and answers are nonsensical.